# setitimer functionality in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I am facing some problems with the usage of `setitimer` functionality.

When I execute the code I couldn't see expected result. The signal handles `printf( )` works when I comment the `while(1)` part in main function (which is my busy executing code). In my understanding both (`main( )` and `signal_handler()`) should run in time sliced fashion or in parallel depending on Linux scheduler.

Can anyone help me out in debugging or correcting my understanding?

Here is the code:

```
void timer_handler (int signum) {

    printf("...\n"); 
    printf ("Timer expired %d times\n", ++count);
} 

void Tmr_Init(void) {

    struct sigaction sa;
    struct itimerval timer; 

    memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
    sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler; 
    sigaction (SIGPROF, &sa, NULL);timer.it_value.tv_sec = 2;

    timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

    setitimer (ITIMER_PROF, &timer, NULL);
} 

int main () {

    Tmr_Init(); 

    /* Do busy work. */
    while (1) {
        printf("In main!!\n"); 
        sleep(2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the code. Also, [avoid using `printf` in the signal handler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16891019/1009479)

Comment: void timer_handler (int signum) {
 printf ("Timer expired %d times\n", ++count);
}


int main ()
{
 
 Tmr_Init();

 /* Do busy work. */
 while (1)
 {
     printf("In main!!\n"); 
     sleep(2);
 }
 return 0;
}

Comment: If you see the code above, if I comment the while(1) code part in main( ) function signal handler functionality works perfect.

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19486688/edit) your question to add more code.

Comment: void timer_handler (int signum){printf("...\n");                     printf ("Timer expired %d times\n", ++count);}

void Tmr_Init(void)
{struct sigaction sa;struct itimerval timer;
memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler; sigaction (SIGPROF, &sa, NULL);timer.it_value.tv_sec = 2; timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1; timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;setitimer (ITIMER_PROF, &timer, NULL);}

int main ()
{Tmr_Init();                                                        /* Do busy work. */while (1){printf("In main!!\n");  sleep(2);}return 0;}

Comment: Hi Ya Hao: Sorry you have to format locally the code what I posted above. I am facing problem in formatting while adding the code.

Comment: No, I mean you need to put the code into the question itself by editing it. Don't post them in the comment.